# Why does the second if-statement behave like this?

Tags: javascript, boolean

The first case will execute, while the latter one will not.
Can you please explain this to me?

```js
function foo() {
  return "bar";
}

if (foo()) {
  console.log("This works!");
}

if (foo() == true) {
  console.log("This does not work!");
}
```

Comment: The string `"bar"` is a truthy value but not loosely equal to the boolean `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The first case `foo()` is implicitly converted to boolean like `if(Boolean(foo()))` which is equal to `if(Boolean("bar"))` where any string that has a length bigger than `0` is converted to `true` (considered `truthy` value)

in the second case you are comparing `"bar"` to `true` where the `==` will try to convert one value type into the other it will fail that is why it's evaluated into `false` in the second case

you can read from [ydkjs](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#explicitly-----boolean) book the full explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
  return "bar";
}
```

this function returns a variable type "bar"

```
if (foo() == true) {
  console.log("This does not work!");
}
```

since we are unsure variable type that foo() return,s the comparison will not work
//if (foo() == true) {

find out the variable type the function returns, and make the necessary comparison

HTH
traja47

Comment: "*since we are unsure variable type that foo() return,s the comparison will not work*" the comparison is not done before the code is ran based on what the function *might* return. It's done based on what it *does* return. `foo = () => Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : "bar"` will also leave us unsure what the return value is but that will not affect the comparison - if a `true` is returned, then `true == true` is still `true.

Comment: do not mix different variable types for a function return value; stick to bool; HTH traja47